# flip animation for right navigation bar button item

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the best way to have the right navigation bar button flip like it does in the ipod when one changes from list view to single song view?  Subclass a custom view?  Are there any api's out there that already do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar, and discusses a few solutions.  The main issue is that the UIBarButtonItem isn't a UIView, so you can't use the UIView transitions. [iPhone flip right button (like iTunes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141013/iphone-flip-right-button-like-itunes)